# Join 2 Oracle query to find data in oracle of different schema

Tags: oracle, join, stored-procedures

I have 2 Oracle queries which I want to join on the basis of `SPAN_ID`. So below are the 2 queries

`QUERY 1`

```
ELSIF PSPANTYPE = 'INTRACITY' THEN
          BEGIN
            OPEN PSPANDATA FOR
           
             SELECT T.SPAN_ID,MAINT_ZONE_CODE,identify_valid_invalid(T.SPAN_ID) as VALIDINFO
              FROM (
                SELECT TO_CHAR(TRIM(RJ_INTRACITY_LINK_ID)) AS SPAN_ID, TO_CHAR(RJ_MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE) AS  MAINT_ZONE_CODE
                FROM NE.MV_SPAN@DB_LINK_NE_VIEWER
              --   FROM  APP_FTTX.span@SAT
                WHERE LENGTH(trim(RJ_INTRACITY_LINK_ID)) > 8 
                AND LENGTH(trim(RJ_INTRACITY_LINK_ID)) < 21            
                AND INVENTORY_STATUS_CODE = 'IPL' 
                AND RJ_MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE = PMAINTZONECODE
                AND NOT REGEXP_LIKE (NVL(TRIM(RJ_INTRACITY_LINK_ID),'-'),'_(9|31|4|7)|(_U)$|(/)$','i')
              MINUS         
              SELECT TO_CHAR(LINK_ID) AS SPAN_ID,TO_CHAR(MAINTENANCEZONECODE) AS MAINT_ZONE_CODE
                  FROM TBL_FIBER_INV_JOBS
                  WHERE SPAN_TYPE = 'INTRACITY'
                  AND MAINTENANCEZONECODE = PMAINTZONECODE
                  ORDER BY 1)T
                  order by 3 desc;
          END;
```

`QUERY 2`

```
select * from APP_LCO.tbl_fip_checklist where spanid in  ('HRFAHBHRODHNSPN001_BU','MHAGBMMHTLVDSPN001_BU','MHBIDKMHAGBMSPN009_BU','MHNVSAMHAGBMSPN005_BU')
and status = 'APPROVED';
```

Comment: And the question is ...? The first code is not a query, it's a part of PL/SQL block

Comment: @astentx: I want to know how I can join the above 2 query which is in different schema

Comment: `select ... from (subquery1) a join (subquery2) b on ...`. It is described in the documentation

Comment: If you have a DB link as long as you specify the scheme where the table is and just join it. There is no particular difference.

Comment: @Gnqz: how to make that dblink join ?

Comment: @astentx we have minus also, could you please helping joining the query